# How to save value to database from custom newsletter field in magento2?

Tags: magento2, database

I am getting only email value in database column my custom subscriber_name column showing null please help me

**db_schema.xml**

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="newsletter_subscriber" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Newsletter Subscriber">
        <column xsi:type="text" name="subscriber_name"  nullable="true" comment="Subscriber Name"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_model_subscriber" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Subscriber" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

**Subscriber.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Subscriber {
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(Http $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aroundSubscribe($subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {
       
        if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('subscriber_name')) { 
            $subscriberName = $this->request->getPost('subscriber_name');
            $subject->setSubscriberName($subscriberName);
            $result = $proceed($email);


            try {
                $subject->save();

            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe.new" before="-" template="Vendor_Module::subscribe.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**newsletter_subscriber_block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet">
      <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="custom_name">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscriber Name</argument>
          <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">subscriber name</argument>
          <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
          <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">ccol-name</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

**Subscribe.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe $block */
?>
<div class="block newsletter">
    <div class="title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Newsletter')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe"
            novalidate
            action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
            method="post"
            data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
            id="newsletter-validate-detail">
            <div class="field newsletter">
                <div class="control">
                    <label for="newsletter">
                        <span class="label">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:')) ?>
                        </span>
                        <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter"
                               placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enter your email address')) ?>"
                               data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}'
                               data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                        />
                        <div class="field subscriber_name">
                            <label class="label" for="subscriber_name"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscriber Name')) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="subscriber_name" type="text" id="subscriber_name" placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscriber Name')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="action subscribe primary"
                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscribe')) ?>"
                        type="submit"
                        aria-label="Subscribe">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscribe')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Customer/js/block-submit-on-send": {
                "formId": "newsletter-validate-detail"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction as you can see here:

```
class CustomSubscribe extends SubscriberController implements HttpPostActionInterface
{

    /**
     * New subscription action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
            $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

        try {
            $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
            $this->validateGuestSubscription();
            $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

            $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
            if ($subscriber->getId()
                && (int) $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() === Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
            ) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                );
            }

            $status = (int) $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($status));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
        }
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $redirect */
    $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $redirectUrl = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
    return $redirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
}
}
```

The Subscribe method takes only the Email parameter from the post action, so your plugin probably tries to save something that is null.

I suggest you in your case to create your own subscribe controller under your module extending the Magento base model to implement your customSubscribe:

Vendor/Module/Controller/Subscriber/CustomSubscriber:

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email') && $this->getRequest()->getPost('custom_name')) {
        $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $customName = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('custom_name');

        try {
            $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
            $this->validateGuestSubscription();
            $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

            $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
            if ($subscriber->getId()
                && (int) $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() === Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
            ) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                );
            }

            $status = (int) $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->customSubscribe($email);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($status));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
        }
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $redirect */
    $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $redirectUrl = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
    return $redirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
}
```

And create a new method extending Magento/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber:

in your di.xml:

```
<preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Subscriber" />
```

and then inside your new Vendor\Module\Model\Subscriber:

```
public function customSubscribe($email, $customName)
{
    $this->loadByEmail($email);

    if ($this->getId() && $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
        return $this->getStatus();
    }

    if (!$this->getId()) {
        $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
    }

    $isConfirmNeed = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    ) == 1 ? true : false;

    $isSubscribeOwnEmail = $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()
        && $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() == $email;

    if (!$this->getId() || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
        || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE
    ) {
        if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
            $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
        } else {
            $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
        }
        $this->setSubscriberEmail($email);
        $this->setCustomName($customName);
    }

    if ($isSubscribeOwnEmail) {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
            $this->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId());
            $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $this->setCustomerId(0);
        }
    } else {
        $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $this->setCustomerId(0);
    }

    $this->setStatusChanged(true);

    try {
        /* Save model before sending out email */
        $this->save();
        if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
            $this->sendConfirmationRequestEmail();
        } else {
            $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
        }
        return $this->getStatus();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Exceptions.DirectThrow
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then you have to edit your custom subscriber.phtml changing the form action:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'vendor/module/customSubscribe/' ?>"> .... </form>
```

And create a Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/route.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="module" frontName="module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c12sm13612062pfl.56 - gsmtp getting this type error

Comment: And the smtp is working fine for all the other transaction emails?

Comment: yes i also solved that error

Comment: i am not getting any error  now but i getting null value in my database custom table

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Plugin/CustomerPlugin.php, it seems that the subscribe event triggers a plugin to save data's inside the table, so now that you've got the data from the post, you might want to use extensionAttributes and then save on the newsletter table